# Keycloak behind Traefik not working properly

Tags: keycloak, traefik

I tried a lot of times undestand what's going on, but I'm tired trying and getting nothing!

I downloaded a docker-compose from https://github.com/heyValdemar/keycloak-traefik-letsencrypt-docker-compose.git

Changed some properties, like hostname and e-mail.

That's my compose file:

Here we have 2 dbs one for backup and one for keycloak production, traefik and keycloak.

I commented the https redirection commands, right now I'm not working with certificates.

```
networks:
  keycloak-network:
    external: true
  traefik-network:
    external: true

volumes:
  keycloak-postgres:
  keycloak-postgres-backup:
  keycloak-database-backups:
  traefik-certificates:

services:
  postgres:
    image: ${KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_IMAGE_TAG}
    volumes:
      - keycloak-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - keycloak-network
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "${KEYCLOAK_DB_NAME}", "-U", "${KEYCLOAK_DB_USER}" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 60s
    restart: unless-stopped

  keycloak:
    image: ${KEYCLOAK_IMAGE_TAG}
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_VENDOR: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_TYPE}
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_HOST: postgres
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PORT: 5432
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_NAME: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_NAME}
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_USER}
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_PASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_SCHEMA: public
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USERNAME}
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_ENABLE_HEALTH_ENDPOINTS: 'true'
      KEYCLOAK_ENABLE_STATISTICS: 'true'
      KC_HOSTNAME: ${KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME}
      KC_PROXY: edge
      KC_PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: 'true'
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: 'false'
    networks:
      - keycloak-network
      - traefik-network
    healthcheck:
      test: timeout 10s bash -c ':> /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8080' || exit 1
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 90s
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.rule=Host(`${KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.service=keycloak"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.services.keycloak.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.services.keycloak.loadbalancer.passhostheader=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.middlewares=compresstraefik"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.compresstraefik.compress=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-network"
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy

  traefik:
    image: ${TRAEFIK_IMAGE_TAG}
    command:
      - "--log.level=${TRAEFIK_LOG_LEVEL}"
      - "--accesslog=true"
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--ping=true"
      - "--ping.entrypoint=ping"
      - "--entryPoints.ping.address=:8082"
      - "--entryPoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entryPoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=${TRAEFIK_ACME_EMAIL}"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
      - "--metrics.prometheus=true"
      - "--metrics.prometheus.buckets=0.1,0.3,1.2,5.0"
      - "--global.checkNewVersion=true"
      - "--global.sendAnonymousUsage=false"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - traefik-certificates:/etc/traefik/acme
    networks:
      - traefik-network
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080"
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "wget", "http://localhost:8082/ping","--spider"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 5s
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`${TRAEFIK_HOSTNAME}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.services.dashboard.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.services.dashboard.loadbalancer.passhostheader=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.middlewares=authtraefik"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.authtraefik.basicauth.users=${TRAEFIK_BASIC_AUTH}"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=HostRegexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=web"
#      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
#      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
    restart: unless-stopped

  backups:
    image: ${KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_IMAGE_TAG}
    command: >-
      sh -c 'sleep $KEYCLOAK_BACKUP_INIT_SLEEP &&
      while true; do
        pg_dump -h postgres -p 5432 -d $KEYCLOAK_DB_NAME -U $KEYCLOAK_DB_USER | gzip > $KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_BACKUPS_PATH/$KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_BACKUP_NAME-$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M").gz &&
        find $KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_BACKUPS_PATH -type f -mtime +$KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_BACKUP_PRUNE_DAYS | xargs rm -f &&
        sleep $KEYCLOAK_BACKUP_INTERVAL; done'
    volumes:
      - keycloak-postgres-backup:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - keycloak-database-backups:${KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_BACKUPS_PATH}
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_DB_NAME: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_NAME}
      KEYCLOAK_DB_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_USER}
      PGPASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_PASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_BACKUP_INIT_SLEEP: ${KEYCLOAK_BACKUP_INIT_SLEEP}
      KEYCLOAK_BACKUP_INTERVAL: ${KEYCLOAK_BACKUP_INTERVAL}
      KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_BACKUP_PRUNE_DAYS: ${KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_BACKUP_PRUNE_DAYS}
      KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_BACKUPS_PATH: ${KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_BACKUPS_PATH}
      KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_BACKUP_NAME: ${KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_BACKUP_NAME}
    networks:
      - keycloak-network
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Here is my env variables:

Just like downloaded, changed only TRAEFIK_HOSTNAME and KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME. E-mail I've leave blank to show you guys.

And I Added these two hostnames into my windows host file.

```
# Traefik Variables
TRAEFIK_IMAGE_TAG=traefik:2.9
TRAEFIK_LOG_LEVEL=WARN
TRAEFIK_ACME_EMAIL=
TRAEFIK_HOSTNAME=traefik.keycloak.labs.net
# Basic Authentication for Traefik Dashboard
# Username: traefikadmin
# Passwords must be encoded using MD5, SHA1, or BCrypt https://hostingcanada.org/htpasswd-generator/
TRAEFIK_BASIC_AUTH=traefikadmin:$$2y$$10$$sMzJfirKC75x/hVpiINeZOiSm.Jkity9cn4KwNkRvO7hSQVFc5FLO

# Keycloak Variables
KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_IMAGE_TAG=postgres:14
KEYCLOAK_IMAGE_TAG=bitnami/keycloak:22.0.1
KEYCLOAK_DB_TYPE=postgresql
KEYCLOAK_DB_NAME=keycloakdb
KEYCLOAK_DB_USER=keycloakdbuser
KEYCLOAK_DB_PASSWORD=EqhvLbsPhrkkZjcaGWcV7qT
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USERNAME=keycloakadmin
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=rwXPqspCABJzqh47i723wf9
KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME=keycloak.labs.net
KEYCLOAK_LOG_LEVEL=WARN

# Backup Variables
KEYCLOAK_BACKUP_INIT_SLEEP=30m
KEYCLOAK_BACKUP_INTERVAL=24h
KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_BACKUP_PRUNE_DAYS=7
KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_BACKUPS_PATH=/srv/keycloak-postgres/backups
KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_BACKUP_NAME=keycloak-postgres-backup
```

I've no problem to acess my Traefik, but when I try to acess Keycloak, I only receive: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED or 404 page not found.

localhost:8080/admin
or
keycloak.labs.net/admin

I already read all this post: https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker

Here's my all my docker containers:

[just like docker-compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVQw8.png)

Here's the log from Keycloak, I really didn't got any request to it. Tried a lot.

[keycloak log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Ote.png)

Tried to change ports, hostnames, methods from http to https...
Tried to connect via fisical ip:port.